# dotnet core 2.1.8 setup for OpenApi specification on Mac m1

Tags: macos, .net-core, openapi, apple-m1

I am trying to install dotnet core 2.1.8 for existing OpenAPI specification project.
But I'm getting this error

```
 zsh: command not found: dotnet
```

I have also used `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet /usr/local/bin/` but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by run this code in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

At first remove the dotnet file from `/usr/local/bin/`  and run the code in terminal

you can run `dotnet --version`     to check version.

`/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet` this path is not available in my mac m1.

to find out your path got to the dotnet folder right click on the dotnet application and press and hold option key in your keybord now you copy path.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that .NET core 2.1 won't work in Mac with M1 or M2 as it is not supported in ARM architecture.
.NET 6 is the first version supported with ARM.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos

[image]